# Как определить возможность чтения/переименования/перемещения файла и его права доступа в Java?

Tags: java, файлы, права-доступа

Имеется сервис/thread worker, который с заданной периодичностью ищет файл/-ы в определённой директории/-ях для извлечения из них данных и перемещения прочитанных файлов в директорию/архив. Исходные файлы создаются сторонними сервисами и изменить их (сервисы) не представляется возможным. В некоторых случаях имена файлов содержат текущую метку времени и при взаимодействии с файлом можно быть уверенным в том, что в момент чтения/переименования/перемещения файла сторонний сервис не будет пытаться его перезаписать. Но в некоторых случаях имя файла статическое и в момент чтения/переименования/перемещения такого файла сторонний сервис может пытаться перезаписать файл. Во избежании такой ситуации было принято решение переименовывать файл добавляя к его имени расширение ".tmp". Хоть это и позволило исключить некоторые возможные проблемы, но не все. Так как файлы создаются сторонними сервисами они могут иметь разные права доступа, которые не понятно как проверить. Далее конкретный пример:

```java
File[] _files = getFiles();

for(int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++)
{
    File _file = rename( _files[i], _files[i].getName() + ".tmp" );
}

// ....

private static File rename(File file, String fileName) throws IOException
{
    Path _filePath = file.toPath();
    
    Path _targetPath = Files.move(
                            _filePath,
                            _filePath.resolveSibling( fileName ),
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
                        );

    return _targetPath.toFile();
}
```

Файл/-ы физически на диске присутствуют, но при попытке переименовать метод rename (Files.move) выбрасывает исключение java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\a\b\c.d
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:288)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1421)
    at xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.rename(XxxxXxxxx.java:42)
```

На локальной машине всё работает должным образом. Из всего этого делаю вывод, что у файла какие-то особенные права доступа, но каким образом их проверить? Как определить права доступа, возможность записи/переименования/перемещения файла?

Comment: Imho - от всего уберечься не выйдет. Мешать может что угодно, включая антивирус или хитрый запрет глобальными политиками. Технически, кстати, судя по стеку - move это не переименование, а копирование + удаление. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал попробовать File.renameTo. Под Win переименование возможно, даже если файл занят. Потом останется только дождаться его освобождения (попробовал-ошибка-пауза-попробовал). Ну и попросить админов - расшаренной папке выдать права "всё для всех" с наследованием дочерними объектами.

Comment: @kami [File.renameTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-) считается устаревшим и не рекомендуется к применению. Если методу не удаётся переименовать или переместить файл, он возвращает false, а исключение не возникает, что не даёт никакой информации о том, что пошло не так.

Comment: согласен. Но это не отменяет остального в моем комментарии: все причины проверить не получится, да и какой смысл, если нет возможности влиять на источники данных... И кстати с файлами с меткой времени тоже бывают проблемы: файл уже есть, а запись в него ещё не завершена, мы это проходили.